# Excel 2013 VBA Macro - EntireRow.Insert loop not working right

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel 2013 Home and Office. Does someone have any idea why these lines of code don't work as expected?

```
rSel = ActiveCell.Row

'Insert 10 Rows
For nCol = 1 To 10
      Cells(rSel + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
      nCol = nCol + 1
Next nCol
```

Simply put, the loop is supposed to insert 10 rows below the active cell but I end up with only 8. Even if I changed 10 to a higher number, I end up with 8 new rows only. I also tried a simpler, single line of code (below) but the result is the same.

```
Cells(rSel + 1, 1).EntireRow.Resize(10).Insert
```

Before anyone answers, I want to detail what this is for (in case that helps). The worksheet contains a header in Range A1:F5 and a footer in Range A8:F18. Data Entry starts at cell A6 from a list using Data Validation. The worksheet MUST BE DESIGNED as it is.

As the user picks choices from the list, a new row is inserted below that row. So, if I pick an item from the list at A6, a new row is inserted below that shifting the footer down. At A10 (5th selection), the code above is executed supposedly pushing the footer down 10 rows so that it appears on the 2nd page in its entirety and won't look weird when it's printed out. A set of code then formats and copies the header and pastes those into the new set of rows on the 2nd page above the footer. I will end up with 2 empty rows on page 1 after the 6th and final selection for that page.

Everything else works perfectly except the part when I want to insert 10 new rows because it consistently only gives me 8.

Comment: the `for` command already increments `nCol` by one each time it loops. then you increment it again, so that `nCol` increments by 2 each time around. that causes it to reach 10 much faster.

Comment: @jsotola You are right: the correct answer was already given below.

Comment: makes no difference if you have a header or footer. also makes no difference if a user picks values from a list. makes no difference why you are adding rows.  all that is irrelevant. what is important, is that you are adding rows into a worksheet, and an unexpected number of rows gets added.

Comment: @AlexBell, i have no idea about the level of expertise that OP has. i was giving an explanation as to why `nCol = nCol + 1` was causing the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to insert 10 rows below the `ActiveCell` use the following code snippet:

```
Sub InsertRow()
rSel = ActiveCell.Row
'Insert 10 Rows
For nCol = 1 To 10
      Cells(rSel + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
Next nCol
End Sub
```

(remove that line causing an error: `nCol = nCol + 1`)

For even better performance you can use the following code snippet inserting 10 rows at once:

```
Sub InsertRowBestPerformance()
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    'Insert 10 Rows below ActiveCell
    Rows(r + 1 & ":" & r + 10).EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

This could be written in a compact form with just a single line of code:

```
Rows(ActiveCell.Row + 1 & ":" & ActiveCell.Row + 10).EntireRow.Insert
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you. This clarifies a lot. I totally forgot that "Next" increments the counter variable in a For..Loop. Goes to say that I am getting too old for this, hahaha. Thanks, again.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

just use this command to insert 10 rows

```
activecell.Resize(10).EntireRow.Insert              ' insert above ActiveCell

activecell.offset(1).Resize(10).EntireRow.Insert    ' insert below ActiveCell
```

Comment: I never thought to reverse Resize and EntireRow. Thank you. I think that'll do it, too.

Comment: i somehow missed your single-line 10 row insert. i tried it and it works. i am not sure why it did not work for you. ... your code inserts 10 rows below the activecell